# FullCalendar rendering background color in month view

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I use the following way to put new events in my calendar:

```
$.each(daten.variable, function(i, v){
    var newEvent = new Object();
    //
    newEvent.typ = 'Abwesenheit';
    newEvent.start = von;
    newEvent.end = bis;
    newEvent.rendering = 'background';
    newEvent.backgroundColor = 'red';
    //
    $('#id').fullCalendar('renderEvent', newEvent, true);
})
```

This works fine for the day view and the week view. But it does not work for the month view. How can I render the background event for the month view?

Answer (score 3):

`.rendering = 'background';` is only shown in the month view when the event is an allDay event. So add this property to your objects:

```
newEvent.allDay = true;
```

[Here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ofam4yex/) to show that background events work in month view.

Comment: Hi, thanks another time! I forget the newEvent.start for the month-view. Now it works fine :-D

Comment: @schildmi I'm glad you resolved your issue, If my answer helped please accept it :).